# Angular 8 http subrequests for children with mapping

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular8

I have to do the following requests inside one call to `getTree()` which has to return an `Observable<TreeNode>`.

- begin transaction
- get parent node (result gives me an array with children ids)

  - for each child id, get child node and replace number with child object
- end transaction

I have problems with the nested children map request

```ts
    getTree(): Observable<TreeNode> {
        return this.getTransactionId().pipe(
            concatMap(trx => {return this.getRootNode(trx, 50);}),
            tap(result => {this.transactionClose().subscribe()})
        ) as Observable<TreeNode>;
    }

    getRootNode(trx: number, nodeId: number): Observable<TreeNode> {
        this.log('fetching root node '+ nodeId);
        var urlRootNode = config['apiUrl'] + `/dataview/perspective/get_root_nodes/trx=${trx}&id=${nodeId}`;
        return this.http.get<TreeNode>(urlRootNode).pipe(
            map(data => { 
                this.log('got root node data ' + data);
                let node = data[0]; 
                node.children = node.children.map(id => {
                    return this.getNodeChild(trx, id).subscribe();
                    // this is where I need help, because
                    // right now, the subscriber of getTree gets notified before the children are loaded
                });


                return node;
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError<TreeNode>('getRootNode'))
        )
    }

    getNodeChild(trx: number, nodeId: number): Observable<TreeNode> {
        this.log('fetching node '+ nodeId);
        var urlNode = config['apiUrl'] + `/dataview/node/get_children/trx=${trx}&id=${nodeId}`;
        return this.http.get<TreeNode>(urlNode).pipe(
            map(data => { 
                this.log('got node data ' + data);
                let node = data[0];                 

                return node;
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError<TreeNode>('getNodeChild'))
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible to make in the next way (changes: `switchMap` added, return is from zipped & mapped source)

```
getRootNode(trx: number, nodeId: number): Observable<TreeNode> {
    this.log('fetching root node '+ nodeId);
    var urlRootNode = config['apiUrl'] + `/dataview/perspective/get_root_nodes/trx=${trx}&id=${nodeId}`;
    return this.http.get<TreeNode>(urlRootNode).pipe(
        switchMap(data => { 
            this.log('got root node data ' + data);
            let node = data[0]; 
            let children$ = zip(...node.children.map(id => {
                return this.getNodeChild(trx, id)
            }));


            return children$.pipe(map(children => node.children = children), map(()=> node));
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError<TreeNode>('getRootNode'))
    )
}
```

Comment: Try to add ... before node.children.map

Comment: I've prepared similar example for you - please, check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7f5pvg